# Python counting characters in a line

Tags: python

It's supposed to count the amount of lines and the amount of characters  in the line.

I cannot add any more variables to my display function, as the professor said to use 2.

I've gotten it to count the characters in the line correctly if I change the zXX= zXX + 1
to zXX = w
but if i do that it will not count the number of lines, if someone could help I'd greatly appreciate it.

Currently I have:

> ```
> def display(x, y):
>      y = str(y)
>      varx = str(len(y))
>      vary = y + "#" + x + "#" + varx
>
>      return vary.rjust(3)
>
>
> def main(): 
>      script = '''Grandson|Cough, cough, cough. Cough, cough, cough. {Grandson is on the bed, playing video game.} Mother|{Enters.} Hi, honey. Grandson|Hi, Mom. Mother|{Kisses son and feels his forehead.} You feeling any better? Grandson|A little bit. Mother|Guess what? Grandson|What? Mother|Your Grandfather's here. {Opens curtains.} Grandson|Mom, can't you tell him I'm sick? Mother|You're sick? That's why he's here. Grandson|He'll pinch my cheek. I hate that. Mother|Maybe he won't. Grandfather|{Entering with a flourish.} Heyyyy!! How's the sickie? Heh? {Pinches boy's cheek.  Boy looks at mother accusingly.} Mother|I think I'll leave you two pals alone. {Exits.} Grandfather|I brought you a special present. Grandson|What is it? Grandfather|Open it up. Grandson|{Opens the package. Disappointed.} A book? Grandfather|That's right. When I was your age, television was called books. And this is a special book. It was the book my father used to read to me when I was sick, {takes book} and I used to read it to your father. And today I'm gonna read it to you. Grandson|Has it got any sports in it? Grandfather|Are you kidding? Fencing, fighting, torture, revenge, giants, monsters, chases, escapes, true love, miracles... Grandson|Doesn't sound too bad. I'll try to stay awake. {Turns off TV.} Grandfather|Oh, well, thank you very much, very nice of you. Your vote of confidence is overwhelming. All right. {Puts glasses on.} The Princess Bride, by S. Morgenstern. Chapter One. Buttercup was raised on a small farm in the country of Florin.'''
>
>      zX = script.split('\n')
>      #print(zX)
>      zXX = 0
>      for w in zX:
>          #print(zX[zXX:(zXX + 1)])
>          zXXXX = w.split('|')
>          #print(zXXXX)
>          zXXX = zXXXX[0].upper() + " " + zXXXX[1]
>          #print(zXXX)
>          zXX = zXX + 1
>          print(display(zXXX, zXX))
> main()
> ```

The output is:

1#GRANDSON Cough, cough, cough. Cough, cough, cough. {Grandson is on the bed, playing video game.}#1

2#MOTHER {Enters.} Hi, honey.#1

3#GRANDSON Hi, Mom.#1

4#MOTHER {Kisses son and feels his forehead.} You feeling any better?#1

5#GRANDSON A little bit.#1

6#MOTHER Guess what?#1

7#GRANDSON What?#1

8#MOTHER Your Grandfather's here. {Opens curtains.}#1

9#GRANDSON Mom, can't you tell him I'm sick?#1

10#MOTHER You're sick? That's why he's here.#2

11#GRANDSON He'll pinch my cheek. I hate that.#2

12#MOTHER Maybe he won't.#2

13#GRANDFATHER {Entering with a flourish.} Heyyyy!! How's the sickie? Heh?
{Pinches boy's cheek.  Boy looks at mother accusingly.}#2

14#MOTHER I think I'll leave you two pals alone. {Exits.}#2

15#GRANDFATHER I brought you a special present.#2

16#GRANDSON What is it?#2

17#GRANDFATHER Open it up.#2

18#GRANDSON {Opens the package. Disappointed.} A book?#2

19#GRANDFATHER That's right. When I was your age, television was called books. And this is a special book. It was the book my father used to read to me when I was sick, {takes book} and I used to read it to your father. And today I'm gonna read it to you.#2

20#GRANDSON Has it got any sports in it?#2

21#GRANDFATHER Are you kidding? Fencing, fighting, torture, revenge, giants, monsters, chases, escapes, true love, miracles...#2

22#GRANDSON Doesn't sound too bad. I'll try to stay awake. {Turns off TV.}#2

23#GRANDFATHER Oh, well, thank you very much, very nice of you. Your vote of confidence is overwhelming. All right. {Puts glasses on.} The Princess Bride, by S. Morgenstern. Chapter One. Buttercup was raised on a small farm in the country of Florin.#2

Comment: `zX`, `zXX`, `zXXXX` - Every time a variable is named as such, a kitten dies.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: Fix your indentation so that your program runs.  Fix your naming so that your program is readable.  Then fix your example, so that your output matches what you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I got past the formatting, and variable names, and that you didn't include the line breaks in 'script', I'm pretty sure that the issue is that you have:

```
varx = str(len(y))
```

Instead of:

```
varx = str(len(x))
```

Though that is based on my interpretation of what you provided